# Convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{2^n}$

Tags: power-series

Let formally $f(z) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{2^n}$. What is the raduis of convergence of this series ?

Comment: Do you know the Cauchy-Hadamard formula for the radius of convergence?

Comment: yes but here I must have something like $\sum_n a_n z^n$ s.t. then $1/R = \limsup |a_n|^{1/n}$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Well, you can write $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{2^n}$ in the form $\sum_{k = 0}^\infty a_k z^k$. You just need to determine the $a_k$.

Comment: Why not just apply the Root Test to the terms $z^{2^n}$?

Comment: [Different but related question about lacunary series I thought was fun to mention.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84779/fractal-behavior-along-the-boundary-of-convergence)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to think of how to apply any special test or theorem to this. Just think about how the terms grow, and how it compares to the most basic series you've seen before e.g. geometric series. If $|z|<1$ then the size of the terms drops off very quickly. Prove the series converges absolutely (and hence converges) if $|z|<1.$ Now see what happens where $z=1$ and this will determine the radius of convergence.

Comment: Well said. It is not even necessary to rewrite this as a series $\sum\limits_na_nz^n$. (A similarly lacunary series was posted a while ago on the site.)

Answer (score 1):

Your series is

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kz^k\;,\;\;a_k=\begin{cases}0&,\;\;k\;\;\text{is not a power of}\;\;2\\{}\\1&,\;\;\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Now, you can try the usual ways to find out the convergence radius, say

$$\sqrt[k]{a_k}=\begin{cases}0&,\;\;k\;\;\text{is not a power of}\;\;2\\{}\\1&,\;\;\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

And thus the $\,\text{sup lim}\;$ of the above is....

Comment: Is it not $a_k = 1$ if $k$ is a power of $2$ ?

Comment: This would give $\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} |a_n|^{1/n} = \inf_{m \geq 0} \sup_{n \geq m} |a_n|^{1/n} = \inf_{n \geq 0} 1  = 1$ I guess.

Comment: I suck today way more than I usually do...thanks all.

Comment: We have $\sum_n z^{2^n} = z+z^2+z^4+z^8 + \cdots$ Why is this equal to $\sum_n a_kz^k$ ?

Comment: Made a few fixes for you. (Hope you don't mind.) I wasn't sure what "Bow" was supposed to be, though.

Comment: Ok now it looks good.

Comment: Ah, "Now"! Fixed.